# Inconsistent Gradle Version between grade-wrapper.properties and actual version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.0.1'
}

group = 'TidBiT'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.4.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

This is the error that I get:

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 5 (5.6.x only) or Gradle 6 (6.3 or later). The current version is Gradle 6.2.2
```

I am no expert in gradle. Most of the time I just copy and past stuff from the web until everything works. However it looks to me there is an inconsistency between the gradle version that the system is detecting and the gradle version that I want that it is also declared in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Do you launch your build with gradle wrapper? (gradlew / gradlew.bat)?

Comment: No, I use commands like `gradle clean` and `gradle bootRun`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the wrapper:

`./gradlew clean` or `./gradlew bootRun`, not `gradle clean` or `gradle bootRun`

If you use Windows:

`gradlew.bat clean` or `gradlew.bat bootRun`

If you don't see these files, generate them with `gradle wrapper`

---

UPD: The difference is that `gradle` uses the version you installed on your machine. Wrapper does the following steps:

1. Download gradle distribution with version you mentioned in gradle.properties
2. Use the downloaded distribution whenever `gradlew` is used.

Comment: Can you please explain what's the difference?

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation